# Add dynamic content from template in md-tab angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```js
var app=angular.module('app',['ngRoute','ng-breadcrumbs','ngMaterial','ngAnimate','ngAria','ControllerModule']).config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider)
{
 
 $routeProvider.when('/',{
  
  templateUrl:'view/login/login.html',
  controller:'loginController',  
 }).when('/dashboard/',{
  
  templateUrl:'view/dashboard/dashboardBodyTab1.html',
  controller:'dashboardController',
  activetab:'tab1',
  label:'Integration of Behavioral Health and Primary Care'
 }).
 when('/dashboard/tab2/',{
  templateUrl:'view/dashboard/dashboardBodyTab2.html',
  controller:'dashboardController',
  activetab:'tab2',
  label:'Ambulatory Care Redesign:Primary Care'
 }).
 when('/dashboard/tab3/',{
  templateUrl:'view/dashboard/dashboardBodyTab3.html',
  controller:'dashboardController',
  activetab:'tab3',
  label:'Ambulatory Care Redesign:Specialty Care'
 }).
 when('/dashboard/tab4/',{
  templateUrl:'view/dashboard/dashboardBodyTab4.html',
  controller:'dashboardController',
  activetab:'tab4',
  label:'Patient Safety in the Ambulatory Setting'
 }).
 when('/dashboard/tab5/',{
  templateUrl:'view/dashboard/dashboardBodyTab5.html',
  controller:'dashboardController',
  activetab:'tab5',
  label:'Million Hearts Initiative'
 }).
  otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
                                                                                                                        }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/bower-angular-route/master/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
 <md-toolbar class="md-medium-tall">
        <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs>
         <md-tab label="Integration of Behavioral Health and Primary Care" ><span class="vDivider"></md-tab>
         <md-tab label="Ambulatory Care Redesign: Primary Care"></md-tab>
         <md-tab label="Ambulatory Care Redesign: Specialty Care"></md-tab>
         <md-tab label="Patient Safety in the Ambulatory Setting"></md-tab>
         <md-tab label="Million Hearts Initiative"><span class="vDivider"></md-tab>
         
        </md-tabs>
        </md-toolbar>
      </div>
```

I want to add content to `<md-tab>` dynamically. Above are my `HTML` page and `app.js` file for routing. I want to change the content by using `ngRoute`.

I have 5 tabs in my `HTML` page, if I select tab1 then `url` sholud be set as `/dashboard/` so that `ngRoute` will set the `templateUrl` as `view/dashboard/dashboardBodyTab1.html`  and `controller` as `dashboardController` for tab1. Same will be applied to tab2, tab3, tab4 & tab5. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this md-tab is a directive ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [ng-view](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) in your HTML so that as per route changes the route content reflects in your HTML.

```
<div ng-app = "mainApp">
   ...
   <div ng-view></div>

</div>
```

[Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Satyanki. Can you please tell me where should I place ng-view in my HTML page so that its content will change according to the tabs?

Comment: Put <div ng-view></div> after </md-toolbar> . If this helps you , please mark my answer as accepted. Thanks!